# System.Xml.dll There is an error in XML file (1,1921)

Tags: xml, vb.net

I got an error
„System.InvalidOperationException” in System.Xml.dll
There is an error in XML file (1, 1921).

I have absolutely no idea what to do with that.

It's connected with another error

"Cannot assign object of type System.Xml.XmlNode to SenditApi.returnStructSPUserLogin" <- this one is about login in to Sendit API which is a sandbox for a delivery company.

Any suggestions? :(

Comment: Save the xml file/text locally and open in an xml editor to see what the issue is.

Comment: You mean System.Xml.dll?
Because if you mean this part about cannot assign... I have no file/text there just a login, password and API key

Comment: @San Does it have [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360)? That will point out variable type mismatches for you, and in some cases suggest solutions.

Comment: Can you show the line of code that throws the InvaidOperation error?

Comment: user = sendit.SPUserLogin(apiKey, login, password, lang)